# Call Function When WebView Changes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

So, I've been looking at the documentation and Googling, but I can't figure out how to call a method when my WebView (OSX, not iOS), changes... All the examples seem to be for iOS. My code looks like this:

SNAFAppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface SNAFAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *browser;

- (IBAction)forwards:(id)sender;


@end
```

SNAFAppDelegate.m

```
#import "SNAFAppDelegate.h"

@implementation SNAFAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize browser = _b;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[_b mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"]]];
}

@end
```

SNAFBrowser.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebView.h> 
#import <WebKit/WebFrame.h>
#import <WebKit/WebEditingDelegate.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>


@interface SNAFBrowser : WebView

@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *browser;

@end
```

SNAFBrowser.m

```
#import "SNAFBrowser.h"

@implementation SNAFBrowser

@synthesize browser = _b;

- (void)webViewDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
}

@end
```

Then, in my MainMenu.xib file, I linked the Outlet "browser" from the AppDelegate to the WebView and set the WebView's custom class to SNAFBrowser.

Essentially, I just want to know when the webview loads another page.

I'm probably doing something ridiculously stupid, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: This method is of WebEditingDelegate protocol, you need to confirm to this protocol and set delegate to self.

Comment: I just tried adding `[_b setDelegate: self];` to the webViewDidChange method, but it gives me `No visible @interface for 'WebView' declares the selector 'setDelegate:' What do you mean by confirming the protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [WebFrameLoadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, and see which methods are suitable to implement, for example `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:`.

Example:

```
@interface SNAFBrowser : WebView <WebFrameLoadDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation SNAFBrowser
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
   NSLog(@"Something got loaded!");
}
...
@end
```

Comment: It gives me `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'WebFrameLoadDelegate'`

Comment: How did you fixed it @citruspi?

Comment: @Mc The protocol is informal, meaning it isn't declared as such, you can just implement the methods from the protocol that you need and set an instance of that class to the WebFrameLoadDelegate of the WebView.